# combining pandas dataframes of different sampling rates

Tags: python, pandas

I have three pandas dataframes containing data that was recorded during a test. One frame is for temperature, the other for vacuum, and the other for voltage.

The data was captured independently, so that time values for each frame don't line up. Only occasionally does a time stamp from one frame have a duplicate in another frame.

What I would like to do is combine these into one data frame and then interpolate the missing values such that I have a complete dataframe.

I'm new to pandas and have been poking around, but I don't feel like I've got anywhere or if I'm even on the right path.

Comment: The basic idea is to settle on common datetime index to use for all the dataframes.  It sounds like you want to take the union of all the observed times, so this should be easy.  Something like pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).fillna().  But until you post some sample data and what you expect, you won't get a full answer from anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng1 = pd.date_range(
    '1/1/2012', 
    periods=10, 
    freq='H'
)

s1 = pd.Series(
    np.arange(10),
    index=rng1
)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'temp': s1}
)

s2 = pd.Series(
    np.arange(5, 10),
    index=['1/1/2012 01:20:00',
           '1/1/2012 01:40:00',
           '1/1/2012 02:00:00',
           '1/1/2012 05:30:00',
           '1/1/2012 06:00:00']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'voltage': s2},
)

print df1
print df2 

--output:--
                     temp
2012-01-01 00:00:00     0
2012-01-01 01:00:00     1
2012-01-01 02:00:00     2
2012-01-01 03:00:00     3
2012-01-01 04:00:00     4
2012-01-01 05:00:00     5
2012-01-01 06:00:00     6
2012-01-01 07:00:00     7
2012-01-01 08:00:00     8
2012-01-01 09:00:00     9

                   voltage
1/1/2012 01:20:00        5
1/1/2012 01:40:00        6
1/1/2012 02:00:00        7
1/1/2012 05:30:00        8
1/1/2012 06:00:00        9


combined = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
print combined

--output:--
                     temp  voltage
2012-01-01 00:00:00     0      NaN
2012-01-01 01:00:00     1      NaN
2012-01-01 01:20:00   NaN        5
2012-01-01 01:40:00   NaN        6
2012-01-01 02:00:00     2        7
2012-01-01 03:00:00     3      NaN
2012-01-01 04:00:00     4      NaN
2012-01-01 05:00:00     5      NaN
2012-01-01 05:30:00   NaN        8
2012-01-01 06:00:00     6        9
2012-01-01 07:00:00     7      NaN
2012-01-01 08:00:00     8      NaN
2012-01-01 09:00:00     9      NaN

combined = combined.apply(
    pd.Series.interpolate, 
    args=('time',) 
)

print combined

--output:--
                         temp   voltage
2012-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000       NaN
2012-01-01 01:00:00  1.000000       NaN
2012-01-01 01:20:00  1.333333  5.000000
2012-01-01 01:40:00  1.666667  6.000000
2012-01-01 02:00:00  2.000000  7.000000
2012-01-01 03:00:00  3.000000  7.285714
2012-01-01 04:00:00  4.000000  7.571429
2012-01-01 05:00:00  5.000000  7.857143
2012-01-01 05:30:00  5.500000  8.000000
2012-01-01 06:00:00  6.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 07:00:00  7.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 08:00:00  8.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 09:00:00  9.000000  9.000000

print combined.fillna(method='backfill')

--output:--
                         temp   voltage
2012-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000  5.000000
2012-01-01 01:00:00  1.000000  5.000000
2012-01-01 01:20:00  1.333333  5.000000
2012-01-01 01:40:00  1.666667  6.000000
2012-01-01 02:00:00  2.000000  7.000000
2012-01-01 03:00:00  3.000000  7.285714
2012-01-01 04:00:00  4.000000  7.571429
2012-01-01 05:00:00  5.000000  7.857143
2012-01-01 05:30:00  5.500000  8.000000
2012-01-01 06:00:00  6.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 07:00:00  7.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 08:00:00  8.000000  9.000000
2012-01-01 09:00:00  9.000000  9.000000
```