# Fit Data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am querying a database for a few variables from an experiment, one at a time and storing the data in a Pandas DataFrame. I can get the data that I need, looks as below for instance:

```
     file       time    variableid  data
0      1      1503657        1       11
1      1      1503757        1       22
```

There is data for several variables that I will be grabbing like this, and then I will be combining them into a single DataFrame to be output to a csv. Each variable's data column will be added as a new column with the corresponding name of the variable (as the file_id should always be the same). The time column values might be different (one DF could be longer than the other, the data wasn't sampled at all of the same times, etc), but if I merge the tables on the time (and file) column, then any discrepancies are filled in with NaN (and I will fill them in with DF.fillna(0)) and the DF can be resorted by the time.

What I need though is a way to filter the data so that it fits a certain rate, such as every 100 milliseconds (1503700,1503800,...). The datapoint itself doesn't have to fit that rate exactly (and in fact the data rarely falls on a time that ends in 00 for instance), but it should be the closest matching data for that time (it could be the closest before or after that time actually, as long as it is consistent throughout).

I thought about iterating over all the values in the time column and adding the row with the closest time one by one (I would first create a blank DF with the desired times), but there are sometimes 50,000+ rows in a sample table. I found an answer about interpolating (link below), but I don't really want to add or modify any of the data itself, just pull the rows that most closely match the rate that I want to sample the data (one reason is some of the data is binary and I wouldn't want to end up with something like 0.5 because the before desired time and after desired time values were 0 and 1). Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

[combining pandas dataframes of different sampling rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010774/combining-pandas-dataframes-of-different-sampling-rates)

Comment: You haven't finished simplifying this question yet -- keep going until you have sample inputs and a sample output. Currently I can't even tell if you want to resample when you query, when you concatenate variable results, or when you write to csv.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure either! If you had an example or suggestion of how to resample at any of those stages it would be helpful to at least see what that would look like. I already have some code that gets me to this stage (all of the DFs for the different variables merged into a single table), so resampling the full table seems to me like the way to go, but I've been wrong before and will be again.

Comment: "*keep going until you have sample inputs and a sample output*".  You're really expected to have not only a clear statement of the problem, but your best, succinct sample code trying to solve it, before you post a question.

Comment: I'll keep working on it then and update when I have something more substantial to show.

Comment: I figured it out, is it appropriate to answer your own question? My solution was pretty similar to the answer to the question I linked to, however, maybe it should just be marked as duplicate...

Comment: Your judgement. Whichever makes a site most useful. If you decide this is unique, edit it a bit to make that clear to a searcher. Does the linked question have the binary data problem, for instance?